# Visual C# - Compiler Options

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the compiler options in Visual Studio 2010 (Visual C#). Does anyone know how I can access these?

Comment: Most of the compiler options are available to configure on a project-by-project basis in the "Properties" page for that project -- is there some particular option you need and can't find?

Comment: Which options are you looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click over the project name in the solution explorer to get the Properties dialog.

Select the **Build** tab.

--

Note that as of VS2015, some options have been placed under the Build tab / [Advanced] button. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp?view=vs-2015)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for Project Properties.
Double-click the Properties node underneath the project in Solution Explorer.